# Given a string, need to find if a permutation of its characters forms a palindrome

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a string, need to find if a permutation of its characters forms a palindrome.

Hi i was trying to find out permutation of characters of a given string is palindrome. I have written code which is working for some test cases but failing for others.
If i giving input as vqhsbe its working fine getting correct response

if i give input as aabbc expected output should be True but getting output as True
SO when i am giving even character string it is working fine and its not working for odd character string.

```
string=input()
def is_palindrome(s):
    odd_counter = 0
    for letter in s:
        if s.count(letter) % 2 != 0:
            odd_counter += 1

    if odd_counter > 1:
        return False
    return True

# Driver program 
if(is_palindrome("string")) : 
    print("Yes") 
else : 
    print("No")
```

if input is - vqhsbe  expected output False(this scenario it is working)
if input is - aabbc   expected output True ( this scenario failing)

Comment: is_palindrome of "aabbc" return True on my test. I suspect the reason your test is failing is that you are calling the function with "string" (the string) instead of string (variable).

Comment: Your code fails on the input `"xxx"`; do you see why?

Comment: Hi Arthur ,yes you are correct i was calling the function with "string". Now its working fine. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Naming a variable `string` is a terrible idea, be careful!

Answer (score 0):

First, here are two slight variations on a brute-force method.

```py
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations


def is_palindrome(s_in):
    return s_in == s_in[::-1]


def any_perm_palindrome(s_in):
    dist_perms = (''.join(curr_perm) for curr_perm in multiset_permutations(s_in))
    return any((is_palindrome(curr_perm) for curr_perm in dist_perms))
```

```py
import itertools as itt


def is_palindrome(s_in):
    return s_in == s_in[::-1]


def any_perm_palindrome(s_in):
    dist_perms = (''.join(curr_perm) for curr_perm in set(itt.permutations(s_in)))
    return any((is_palindrome(curr_perm) for curr_perm in dist_perms))
```

---

Here are two more solutions, which are variations on your original algorithm.

```py
import collections as colls


def is_palindrome(s_in):
    return s_in == s_in[::-1]


def any_perm_palindrome(s_in):
    counts = colls.Counter(s_in).values()
    return [curr_count % 2 != 0 for curr_count in counts].count(True) < 2
```

```py
import collections as colls


def is_palindrome(s_in):
    return s_in == s_in[::-1]


def any_perm_palindrome(s_in):
    counts = colls.Counter(s_in).values()
    odd_count = 0
    for curr_count in counts:
        if curr_count % 2 != 0:
            odd_count += 1
            if odd_count > 1:
                return False
    else:
        return True
```

---

Finally, here are some handy `assert`s to check any solution. Let me know if I can improve these!

```py
assert any_perm_palindrome('aabbccc') is True
assert any_perm_palindrome('aa') is True
assert any_perm_palindrome('aaa') is True
assert any_perm_palindrome('abc') is False
assert any_perm_palindrome('ac') is False
assert any_perm_palindrome('') is True
```